# The file produced unpacking a kernel file with (gunzip and cpio),overwriting some files and repacking everything,is not bootable

Tags: debian, find, archive, cpio

How the title says,I'm trying to unpacking a kernel file (let's say the first one : initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64.gz) with gunzip and cpio,overwriting some files and repacking everything. The issue is that the new kernel file produced is not bootable. Someone can help me to understand why ? Even the size is different. What I would like to do is to alter the content of the initrd.img* files because I'm trying to customize the Debian 11 ISO image with a set of new configuration files,logos and images using CUBIC on Ubuntu 22.04 as host os and Debian 11 as "guest" inside CUBIC. Below are the commands that I have issued :

```
mkdir /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels
mkdir /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped
mkdir /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64

cd /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/

gunzip -k initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64.gz

mkdir /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64

cpio -idv < initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64 -D /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64


mkdir -p usr/share/plymouth/
mkdir -p usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/

cp /usr/share/plymouth/debian-logo.png usr/share/plymouth/

cp /usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/debian.png usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/

cp /usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/logo.png usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/


cp usr/share/plymouth/debian-logo.png /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64/usr/share/plymouth/

cp usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/debian.png /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64/usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld

cp usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld/logo.png /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64/usr/share/plymouth/themes/homeworld

cd /home/ziomario/Scrivania/PassT-Cubic/kernels/unzipped/initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64

find . -print -depth | cpio -o > ../../initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64

find: warning: you have specified the global option -depth after the  argument
-print, but global options are not positional, i.e., -depth  affects tests
specified before it as well as those specified after it.   Please specify global
options before other arguments.

893621 blocks

cd ../..

gzip initrd.img-5.10.0-18-amd64
```

After "burning" a new ISO image with CUBIC and chosing the default kernel to boot with, I seen that the produced kernel files are not able to boot. Infact their size are bigger than the original ones. This is the error reported when I tried to boot them within a VM :

https://ibb.co/rm5WRSz

I don't know why. Inside the kernel files It seems that everything is ok. I have placed the wrong files in my google drive. Maybe you want to test them on your side ? Thanks for your very very useful support.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16z5INJTSB3YcpzE980q9eqRIRVG02-JH?usp=sharing

Anyway,the error reported is : https://ibb.co/rm5WRSz

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
find . -depth | cpio --create --format='newc' > ../../initrd.img-5.10.0-19-amd64
```